# ComboBox SelectedIndex Binding -1 or 0 not selecting first item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that writes to a config file when the `SelectedItem` is changed.
I want to use `SelectedIndex = -1` as a fallback in case the `SelectedItem` is missing.

I don't want `SelectedIndex` to fire and write to the config file at program startup, so I put the event handler in `C#` `Window_Loaded()` instead of the `XAML`.

---

The problem is `Video_SelectedIndex = -1` doesn't select anything, it leaves the `SelectedItem` blank.

---

#### MainWindow

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cboPlugin_Video.SelectedIndex += VM.PluginsView.Video_SelectedIndex; // <-- Problem here
    cboPlugin_Video.SelectionChanged += cboPlugin_Video_SelectionChanged;
```

I tried to bind it another way, but it fires at program startup.

```
cboPlugin_Video.DataContext = VM.PluginsView;
Binding Plugins_Video_SelectedIndexBinding = new Binding() { Source = VM.PluginsView, Path = new PropertyPath("Video_SelectedIndex"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
cboPlugin_Video.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty, Plugins_Video_SelectedIndexBinding);
```

#### XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VM/>
</Window.DataContext>

<ComboBox x:Name="cboPlugin_Video"
          DataContext="{Binding PluginsView}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Video_Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Video_SelectedItem}"
          Margin="10,12,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="22" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Width="140" />
```

#### ViewModel

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    public class PluginsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        private int _Video_SelectedIndex { get; set; }
        public int Video_SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _Video_SelectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_Video_SelectedIndex == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _Video_SelectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Video_SelectedIndex");
            }
        }
```

#### Select Item/Index

```
// Plugin Found
if (test == "Example")
{
    VM.PluginsView.Video_SelectedItem = "Example"; // Works
}

// Missing, Default to First Item
else
{
    VM.PluginsView.Video_SelectedIndex = -1; // <-- Not working
}
```

#### Selection Changed Event

```
private void cboPlugin_Video_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Write to config file
    // Works
}
```

Comment: `The problem is Video_SelectedIndex = -1 doesn't select anything, it leaves the SelectedItem blank.` <- nothing going wrong here, thats the expected behaviour

Comment: Is there a typo? `cboPlugin_Video.SelectedIndex += VM.PluginsView.Video_SelectedIndex;` - shouldn't it be only `=` instead of `+=` ?

Comment: @RandRandom It looks like `+=` and `-1` instead of `0` was the problem, but after changing it to `=`, it now fires at startup.

Comment: @RandRandom I don't think I can properly bind it to the ViewModel. I think I have to pass the `MainWindow` to it and use `mainwindow.cboPlugin_Video.SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: You could register the `SelectionChanged` event on `ContentRendered` instead of loaded https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.contentrendered - this should happen after all the bindings evaluated

Comment: @MattMcManis: Why would setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1 select anything? This is the opposite of that it's supposed to do. What exactly is your issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The value -1 describes that no element is selected. You have to set it to 0 to get the first item.

As described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

To long for comment

Why aren't you writing to config in your setter?

```
private int _Video_SelectedIndex { get; set; }
public int Video_SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _Video_SelectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_Video_SelectedIndex == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Video_SelectedIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Video_SelectedIndex");

       //write to config
    }
}
```

This way you won't get the `SelectionChange` from nothing (-1) to 0, since `_Video_SelectedIndex` will be initialized with 0 and `if (_Video_SelectedIndex == value)` will prevent to trigger if it changes from `0` to `0`.

As a side note, why have you declared `_Video_SelectedIndex` as a property instead of a field?

So why this:

```
private int _Video_SelectedIndex { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
private int _Video_SelectedIndex;
```

Edit:

I can't reproduce your problem, maybe this little test project I did will help you.

If not please make the necessary changes needed to show your problem.

Notice, I have tested both `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="ComboBox with SelectedItem" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />

        <TextBlock Text="ComboBox with SelectedIndex" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Config _config;
    private string _selectedItem;
    private int _selectedIndex;
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; } = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => $"Foo {x}");

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value)
                return;
            
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            
            //write config
            _config.SelectedItem = value;
        }
    }
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => _selectedIndex;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex == value)
                return;
            
            _selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            
            //write config
            _config.SelectedIndex = value;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _config = new Config();
        
        //read config
        _selectedItem = _config.SelectedItem;
        _selectedIndex = _config.SelectedIndex;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Config.cs**

```
public class Config
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        //fake reading stuff from *.config file
        
        //test it with either of those
        
        //SelectedItem = "Foo 2";
        //SelectedIndex = 2;

        SelectedItem = null;
        SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Both `//write config` parts will only hit when the user manually changes the combox value and not automatically on start up.

To use a default value if the config returns `null` or `-1` you could alter this code:

```
//read config
_selectedItem = _config.SelectedItem;
_selectedIndex = _config.SelectedIndex;
```

To this:

```
//read config
_selectedItem = _config.SelectedItem ?? Items.First();
_selectedIndex = _config.SelectedIndex == -1 ? 0 : _config.SelectedIndex;
```

Or to acutally check if the value that was stored in `_config` is still valid you could use this

```
_selectedItem = Items.Contains(_config.SelectedItem) ? _config.SelectedItem : Items.First();
_selectedIndex = _config.SelectedIndex >= Items.Count() || _config.SelectedIndex < 0 ? 0 : _config.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: I tried writing to config in the setter, but binding `SelectedIndex` still fired at startup any way I tried it. The `{ get; set; }` was probably and accident from an example I was following.

Comment: @MattMcManis - did your problem get solved?